# Ruby Array Sort 2 different ways

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I have an array of objects that I'm trying to sort by multiple criteria. Most of the comparisons are just by doing `<=>` on their hashes, so using `sort_by` is very fast, but one of them is more complex.

The array is of soccer teams, and it's currently being sorted like this:

```
teams.sort_by { |item| [item.points, item.goal_dif, item.goals] }
```

However, in case at last 2 teams have identical values on those 3 fields, I want the tiebreaker to be a function that I made, `a_beat_b(teamA, teamB)`.

I tried using `Array.sort`, but it's extremely slow compared to `sort_by` for those first few... My implementation was like this:

`teams.sort ( |a,b| [a.points, a.goals_dif, a.goals] <=> [b.points, b.goals_dif, b.goals])`
It was very slow compared to sort_by. The functions for points, goals_dif and goals require some simple queries, but it gets bogged down if it has to do hundreds.

I'm not very good at Ruby, so not sure where to put my `a_beats_b` in there. (It returns 1, 0 or -1 if A beat, drew or lost to B, repsectively)

Comment: What does your implementation of `a_beat_b` look like? What do you mean when you say you "couldn't get the code right"?

Comment: `a_beat_b` works like a `<=>`, returns 1 if team A has beat B this tournament. 0 if a draw, and -1 if B won. The code for `Array.sort` was like this, `teams.sort ( |a,b| [a.points, a.goals_dif, a.goals] <=> [b.points, b.goals_dif, b.goals])` Didn't know where to put my function. Will edit it in.

Comment: `Array#sort` is the right answer. You should check whether the arrays are identical and then conditionally use `a_beat_b` to to perform the more expensive comparison. Without seeing *how* you tried to implement `Array#sort`, we can't really help you.

Comment: I've edited it in, not sure how to write the sort one to use my function.

Comment: Regarding the slowness: are `points`, `goals_dif` and `goals` expensive methods?

Comment: They just sum 2 simple queries, pretty fast, though all the DB access is bound to slow it down if they're called a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried using `Array.sort`, but it's extremely slow compared to `sort_by` for those first few

This is because `sort` calls the given block several times. Here's an example to show what's going on under the hood: (sorting `"apple"`, `"pear"` and `"fig"` by length)

```
def length(str)
  puts "calculating #{str.inspect}.length"
  str.length
end

array = %w{apple pear fig}
array.sort { |a, b| length(a) <=> length(b) }
#=> ["fig", "pear", "apple"]
```

Output from our `length` method:

```
calculating "apple".length
calculating "pear".length
calculating "apple".length
calculating "fig".length
calculating "pear".length
calculating "fig".length
```

As you can see, `length` is called multiple times during the sort. Imagine that these are database queries.

`sort_by` on the other hand calls the block once for each element, building an internal mapping:

```
array.sort_by { |a| length(a) }
#=> ["fig", "pear", "apple"]
```

Output:

```
calculating "apple".length
calculating "pear".length
calculating "fig".length
```

For expensive operations (like database queries), this is much faster. But it's also less flexible – you can't dynamically compare `a` and `b` any more.

You can however store the results of your (expensive) operation, for example by using a hash: (this is called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization))

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = length(k) }
```

And use the hash within `sort`:

```
array.sort { |a, b| hash[a] <=> hash[b] }
# calculating "apple".length
# calculating "pear".length
# calculating "fig".length
#=> ["fig", "pear", "apple"]
```

After the sort, our hash looks like this:

```
hash #=> {"apple"=>5, "pear"=>4, "fig"=>3}
```

Applied to your code, something like this should work:

```
hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [k.points, k.goal_dif, k.goals] }
teams.sort { |a, b| hash[a] == hash[b] ? a_beats_b(a, b) : hash[a] <=> hash[b] }
```

Comment: Wow, I really have to study what you did there. I already knew about the difference between the sort functions, but there's a lot of awesomeness here. Either way, this is the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Implementation of `sort` with `a_beats_b` included:

```
teams.sort do |a, b|
  result = [a.points, a.goals_dif, a.goals] <=> [b.points, b.goals_dif, b.goals]
  result.zero? ? a_beats_b(a, b) : result
end
```

Comment: That result.zero? thing looks great! This code definitely works, but that sort is still much slower than sort_by, it takes over 5 seconds compared to about 1. If this is the only possible way, I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that, while somewhat complex, has been designed for efficiency. The method uses the following steps.

- Convert each `Team` instance to to an array containing the instance and the three-element array on which the inexpensive sort is to be done.
- Use [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) to sort the arrays by the three-element arrays.
- Use [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) to group the two-element arrays that have equal three-element arrays.
- Map each chunked array element to the `Team` instance in the two-element array.
- Use [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) to map each chunked group of `Team` instances after it has been sorted by the method `a_beat_b(a, b)` (unless the group contains only one team, of course).

**Code**

```
def sort_em(teams)
  teams.map { |t| [t, [t.points, t.goal_dif, t.goals]] }.
        sort_by(&:last).
        chunk(&:last).
        map { |_,tied_teams| tied_teams.map(&:first) }.
        flat_map { |tied_teams| (tied_teams.size == 1) ?
          tied_teams.first : tied_teams.sort { |a,b| a_beat_b(a, b) } }
end
```

**Example**

```
class Team
  attr_reader :name, :points, :goal_dif, :goals
  def initialize(name, points, goal_dif, goals)
    @name, @points, @goal_dif, @goals = name, points, goal_dif, goals
  end
end

teams = [Team.new("bluebirds", 233, 25, 130),
         Team.new("eagles",    233, 18, 105),
         Team.new("jays",      233, 25, 130),
         Team.new("owls",      160, 12, 105),
         Team.new("sparrows",  233, 18, 105)
        ]
  #=> [#<Team:0x007ff2f900e5a8 @name="bluebirds", @points=233, @goal_dif=25, @goals=130>,
  #    #<Team:0x007ff2f900e530 @name="eagles", @points=233, @goal_dif=18, @goals=105>,
  #    #<Team:0x007ff2f900e4b8 @name="jays", @points=233, @goal_dif=25, @goals=130>,
  #    #<Team:0x007ff2f900e440 @name="owls", @points=160, @goal_dif=12, @goals=105>,
  #    #<Team:0x007ff2f900e3c8 @name="sparrows", @points=233, @goal_dif=18, @goals=105>]

def a_beat_b(a, b)
  a.name.size <=> b.name.size
end

sort_em(teams)
  #=> [#<Team:0x007ff2fa845630 @name="owls", @points=160, @goal_dif=12, @goals=105>,
  #    #<Team:0x007ff2fa845720 @name="eagles", @points=233, @goal_dif=18, @goals=105>,
  #    #<Team:0x007ff2fa8455b8 @name="sparrows", @points=233, @goal_dif=18, @goals=105>,
  #    #<Team:0x007ff2fa8456a8 @name="jays", @points=233, @goal_dif=25, @goals=130>,
  #    #<Team:0x007ff2fa8457e8 @name="bluebirds", @points=233, @goal_dif=25, @goals=130>]
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

```
a = teams.map { |t| [t, [t.points, t.goal_dif, t.goals]] }
  #=> [[#<Team:0x007ff2fa8457e8 @name="bluebirds", @points=233, @goal_dif=25, @goals=130>,
  #     [233, 25, 130]],
  #    [#<Team:0x007ff2fa845720 @name="eagles", @points=233, @goal_dif=18, @goals=105>,
  #     [233, 18, 105]],
  #    [#<Team:0x007ff2fa8456a8 @name="jays", @points=233, @goal_dif=25, @goals=130>,
  #     [233, 25, 130]],
  #    [#<Team:0x007ff2fa845630 @name="owls", @points=160, @goal_dif=12, @goals=105>,
  #     [160, 12, 105]],
  #    [#<Team:0x007ff2fa8455b8 @name="sparrows", @points=233, @goal_dif=18, @goals=105>,
  #     [233, 18, 105]]] 
b = a.sort_by(&:last)
  #=> [[#<Team:0x007ff2fa845630 @name="owls", @points=160, @goal_dif=12, @goals=105>,
  #    [160, 12, 105]],
  #   [#<Team:0x007ff2fa845720 @name="eagles", @points=233, @goal_dif=18, @goals=105>,
  #    [233, 18, 105]],
  #   [#<Team:0x007ff2fa8455b8 @name="sparrows", @points=233, @goal_dif=18, @goals=105>,
  #    [233, 18, 105]],
  #   [#<Team:0x007ff2fa8457e8 @name="bluebirds", @points=233, @goal_dif=25, @goals=130>,
  #    [233, 25, 130]],
  #   [#<Team:0x007ff2fa8456a8 @name="jays", @points=233, @goal_dif=25, @goals=130>,
  #    [233, 25, 130]]
  #   ] 
c = b.chunk(&:last)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007ff2fa81dc20>:each>
```

To see what values are generated by the enumerator `c` we can convert it to an array.

```
c.to_a 
  #=> [[[160, 12, 105],
  #     [[#<Team:0x007ff2fa845630 @name="owls",@points=160,@goal_dif=12,@goals=105>,
  #       [160, 12, 105]
  #      ]
  #     ]
  #    ],
  #    [[233, 18, 105],
  #     [[#<Team:0x007ff2fa845720 @name="eagles",@points=233,@goal_dif=18,@goals=105>,
  #       [233, 18, 105]
  #      ],
  #     [#<Team:0x007ff2fa8455b8 @name="sparrows",@points=233,@goal_dif=18,@goals=105>,
  #       [233, 18, 105]
  #     ]
  #    ],
  #    [[233, 25, 130],
  #     [[#<Team:0x007ff2fa8457e8 @name="bluebirds",@points=233,@goal_dif=25,@goals=130>,
  #       [233, 25, 130]
  #      ],
  #      [#<Team:0x007ff2fa8456a8 @name="jays", @points=233,@goal_dif=25,@goals=130>,
  #       [233, 25, 130]
  #      ]
  #     ]
  #    ]
  #   ]
```

```
d = c.map { |_,tied_teams| tied_teams.map(&:first) }
  #=> [[#<Team:0x007ff2fa845630 @name="owls", @points=160, @goal_dif=12, @goals=105>],
  #    [#<Team:0x007ff2fa845720 @name="eagles", @points=233, @goal_dif=18, @goals=105>,
  #     #<Team:0x007ff2fa8455b8 @name="sparrows", @points=233, @goal_dif=18, @goals=105>
  #    ],
  #    [#<Team:0x007ff2fa8457e8 @name="bluebirds", @points=233, @goal_dif=25, @goals=130>,
  #     #<Team:0x007ff2fa8456a8 @name="jays", @points=233, @goal_dif=25, @goals=130>
  #    ]
  #   ] 
d.flat_map { |tied_teams| (tied_teams.size == 1) ?
  tied_teams.first : tied_teams.sort { |a,b| a_beat_b(a, b) } }
  #=> [#<Team:0x007ff2fa845630 @name="owls", @points=160, @goal_dif=12, @goals=105>,
  #    #<Team:0x007ff2fa845720 @name="eagles", @points=233, @goal_dif=18, @goals=105>,
  #    #<Team:0x007ff2fa8455b8 @name="sparrows", @points=233, @goal_dif=18, @goals=105>,
  #    #<Team:0x007ff2fa8456a8 @name="jays", @points=233, @goal_dif=25, @goals=130>,
  #    #<Team:0x007ff2fa8457e8 @name="bluebirds", @points=233, @goal_dif=25, @goals=130>
  #   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size and const of the sorting function this might be an approach:

```
# First group the teams by standard sort:
groups = teams.group_by{|a| [a.points, a.goals_dif, a.goals] }

# For each group that has ties. Run the slow sorter on them:
groups.each{ |_,val| val.sort!{|teamA,teamB| a_beat_b(teamA, teamB)} if val.size > 1 }

# Finally run sort on the keys of the group by:
groups.sort.flat_map(&:last)
```